# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified with c#.net and this_addins office & win8

Tags: c#, database-connection, ms-office

I've written this simple connection in my code:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("data source=localhost;user id=fastecit;password=fastecit");
con.Open();
```

> error= ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

project me c#.net and this_addins office & win8

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means your connection string is not right. Look here for the help with the correct format of the string:

> http://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/

Also, IIRC that specific Oracle provider is no longer supported. You may want to take a look at the [ODP.Net provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html), in which case you want to use this link to help format your connection string:

> http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/

Comment: This error appears only when the project "Excel 2007 Add_in" While it does not appear when the project is  WindowsFormsApplication using the same connection string above.@Joel Coehoom

Comment: i am using c#.net 2010 & win8 & oracle 10g & office 2007